# heroku db rows accidently removed: is it possible to restore it?

Tags: heroku

I deleted all rows in my table by accident for my hobby dev (free) Heroku app.
Is it possible to restore my db rows? Thank you!

Comment: Did you create a backup of the postgres db first?

Comment: No its a hobby plan and i didnt make a back up. So is it impossible?

Comment: Then not sure, but probably, in my view, its now impossible to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Heroku Postgres, it's possible Heroku could restore it from some internal backup, Since you do not have that I highly suggest you reach out to [support](https://www.heroku.com/support). They have some possible recovery tools, but you must go through support and time is of the essence... the news might not be good if you’ve never done a backup.

Thanks